# PHP rename() does not find file with space in filename

Tags: php, rename

I'm using PHP rename() function to move a file. The file has space in the filename though. And for some reason it can't find it. I tried escaping it but that didn't work either. Does someone have an idea what is going on? It is on a Unix system.

```
$filename = basename($file->uri);

// Tried this once didn't work either:
$filename = str_replace(' ', "\ ", $filename);
//

rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$source.'/'.$filename, 
               drupal_realpath($file->uri));
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's space issue. Probably simple your file doesn't exist in the path you give to rename function.

Try to display the path:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$source.'/'.$filename;
```

and make sure this path is really valid in your case